# Zeros of a Laurent series is a finite set

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, laurent-series

Actually, the question seems quite simple but I dont figure out why it is working. Let $f$ be a non zero formal Laurent series. We want to prove that $V(f)$ (the set of $z \in \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ such that $f(z) = 0$) is  a finite set.

Actually, I really wanted to use the  isolated zeroes principle, but I had several problems because I don't have enough hypotheses to apply it as I wanted to do, and even if I tried hard to make it work, I did not succeed. Probably because I don't use explicitly that $f$ is a Laurent series...

Someone would have and idea ?

Thank you !

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$ has infinitely many zeros, the points $\pi k$, for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Locally, in the domain of holomorphic (=analytic) convergence, the zeros are isolated thus in finite number in every compact. The zeros of $\sin(1/(1-z))$ accumulate at $1$, but its Laurent series converges only for $|z|<1$. Something similar holds in higher dimensions, except the zeros aren't points but analytic hypersurfaces.

Comment: Thank you both of you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's true. Take $\sin(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}z^{2n+1}$.

Comment: Yes, indeed... Thank you !